# Why localeCompare can be faster than Collator.compare

Tags: javascript

I have read multiple articles and comments, saying that the usage of Intl.Collator is beneficial in terms of performance while comparing strings. EcmaScript documentation states that localeCompare is just using Collator under the hood, but it might create the new Collator instance per each function call.

That makes sense to me, but I have tested the performance of both options, and the results are surprising. I have created an array of 50000 strings, where each string is a set of 15 lowercase English characters. Then I compared the speed of `array.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b))` and `array.sort(collator.compare)` and created a benchmark, which you can see for yourself here:
https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/27780/0/intlcollatorcompare-vs-localecompare

The consistent result, is that localeCompare is twice as fast in this case. Could you please help me understand why is that?

Note: If I would pass the second argument(for example 'pl') to localeCompare, it would greatly decrease its performance.

Comment: `localeCompare` is slower in firefox, but it's indeed 3 times faster in chrome. Chrome probably doesn't stick to the ecma script spec on that one

Comment: Here is codepen with Collator: https://codepen.io/NiedziolkaMichal/pen/dywQaJd and here is localeCompare: https://codepen.io/NiedziolkaMichal/pen/ExGOrQW . To me speed on firefox looks similar, but on Chrome & on Safari for sure localeCompare is faster.

Comment: I also just run in to this problem, in my case only comparing strings of length one. In Chrome `Collator` is multiple times slower than `localeCompare`, while in Firefox `localeCompare` is somewhat faster. In both cases though 2 comparisons using `===` and `<` are faster than both other options.

Comment: I have a hunch that this might be an effect of a V8 optimization such as [this one](https://v8.dev/blog/v8-release-76#unicode-string-handling).

Answer (score 1):

One possible explanation for this in v8-based browsers like Chrome is that
`localeCompare` has an [optimization](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:v8/src/objects/intl-objects.tq;l=48) for comparing ASCII-only strings
which makes use of lookup tables to compare on [L1 and L3](https://unicode.org/reports/tr10/#Comparison_Levels_Table). I tried
comparing strings containing non-ASCII characters [here](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/27893/0/intlcollatorcompare-vs-stringprototypelocalecompare-v8) and got similar
results for both `localeCompare` and `Intl.Collator`.

Comment: That looks to be correct. I have created a test with characters "{", "|" & "}" which have code points 123, 124, 125 and here localeCompare was significantly faster. Test with characters "…", "†" & "‡" which have code points 133, 134 & 135 has shown no performance advantage for localeCompare. It seems the usage of localeCompare is beneficial as long as we stick with only a single argument.